# springboot x react - Okta OAuth2 (401 error API)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, okta-api

I am working on a react and springboot application and am getting 401 error whenever I make a call to this endpoint [image] Other endpoints are working fine.

I'm not too sure what's causing the issue.

I have 2 configuration files as follows:

DataRestConfig.java

```
package com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.config;

import com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.entity.Book;
import com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.entity.Review;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

@Configuration
public class MyDataRestConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    private String theAllowedOrigins = "http://localhost:3000";
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        HttpMethod[] theUnsupportedActions = {HttpMethod.POST,HttpMethod.PATCH,HttpMethod.DELETE,HttpMethod.PUT };
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Review.class);
        disableHttpMethods(Book.class, config, theUnsupportedActions);
        disableHttpMethods(Review.class, config, theUnsupportedActions);

//        Configure CORS Mapping
        cors.addMapping(config.getBasePath() + "/**")
                .allowedOrigins(theAllowedOrigins);
    }

    private void disableHttpMethods(Class theClass, RepositoryRestConfiguration config, HttpMethod[] theUnsupportedActions) {
        config.getExposureConfiguration()
                .forDomainType(theClass)
                .withItemExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(theUnsupportedActions))
                .withCollectionExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(theUnsupportedActions));
    }

}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.config;

import com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Disable cross site request forgery
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())

                .cors(cors -> {
                    cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
                })

                // Protect endpoints at /api/<type>/secure
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/books/secure/**").authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
                )

                // Add content negotiation strategy
                .setSharedObject(ContentNegotiationStrategy.class,
                        new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy());
        return http.build(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new
                UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }


}
```

I am using okta-spring-boot-starter v2.1.6 and spring-boot-starter-parent v3.1.4.

BookRepository.java

```
package com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.dao;

import com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.entity.Book;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;




public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Long> {
    Page<Book> findByTitleContaining(@RequestParam("title") String title, Pageable pageable);

    Page<Book> findByCategory(@RequestParam("category") String category, Pageable pageable);


}
```

BookController.java

```
package com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.controller;

import com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.entity.Book;
import com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.service.BookService;
import com.luv2code.springbootlibrary.utils.ExtractJWT;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
public class BookController {

    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired //allows you to create Bean without using new keyword
    public BookController(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/secure/currentloans/count")
    public int currentLoansCount(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token) {
        String userEmail = ExtractJWT.payloadJWTExtract(token, "\"sub\"");
        return bookService.currentLoansCount(userEmail);
    }

    @GetMapping("/secure/ischeckedout/byuser")
    public Boolean checkoutBookByUser(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token,
    @RequestParam Long bookId) {
        String userEmail = ExtractJWT.payloadJWTExtract(token, "\"sub\"");
//        System.out.println("user " + userEmail);
        return bookService.checkoutBookByUser(userEmail, bookId);
    }

    @PutMapping("/secure/checkout")
    public Book checkoutBook(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token,
    @RequestParam Long bookId) throws Exception {
        String userEmail = ExtractJWT.payloadJWTExtract(token, "\"sub\"");
        return bookService.checkoutBook(userEmail, bookId);
    }

}
```

Appreciate my help or ideas, thanks!

Comment: Can you upgrade to okta-spring-boot-starter v3.0.5 and see if that helps? v2.1.6 doesn't support Spring Boot 3. You can see what's changed between releases at https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/releases.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before `http.build()`

`Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);`

Comment: Why? What effect has what you propose? How does that solve the described problem?

Comment: It will used to solve the errors with 401 errors of Okta Oauth2

Comment: What immediate effect has what you propose? How does that solve the described problem?